# C/C++ Initialise char array to const char*

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

Say I have a char array, this is ok:

```
char myChars[100] = "hello";
```

But if I have a

```
const char* hello="hello";
char myChars[100] = hello;
```

or

```
const char hello[6]="hello";
char myChars[100] = hello;
```

it's not allowed:

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed intializer
```

Seems to me that these are basically equivalent statements, why is this the case?

Comment: Have you tried `const char myChars[] = "Hello";`?

Comment: I'm using C++ on arduino, I thought the languages were similar in this area if not please explain how they differ

Comment: @Thomas I don't believe that's what's in question.

Comment: Nvm, I'm an idiot.

Comment: `hello` has a completely different type from `myChars`. It's like trying to initialize your grandma from a cat. (By contrast, `"hello"` and `myChars` have reasonably similar types for the initialization to make sense.)

Comment: strcpy() is your answer.

Comment: It will work if you replace `const char* hello="hello";` with `#define hello "hello"`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It may not be in the question, but it is a combination that was left out.

Comment: I removed the C tag. Pick _one_ language.

Comment: @Thomas Fair point.

Comment: @chqrlie Please don't encourage `#define` in C++. It's strongly typed for a reason.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco: the question was originally tagged [c]. The preprocessor is an integral part of C++, considering the rest of the spec, it adds little to the complexity of the language ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because pointers are not arrays, and arrays are not pointers.

These examples are not equivalent; the string literal `"hello"` is not a pointer, but a `const char[6]`, which may be used to initialise your `char myChars[100]` as a special case.

However, if you first make it decay to a pointer, you can't get that array-ness back again later. There's no way, in the general case, for the compiler to know how large the array would be, or that it even is one. Thus, initialising an array from a pointer is invalid, no matter what came before.

Comment: So it's still illegal to do `const char hello[6] = "hello";` and then `char myChars[100] = hello;`, isn't that an equivalent statement to `char myChars[100] = "hello";` ?

Comment: @jdex. No. You need to think like a computer. `char myChars[100] = "hello";` says make an array of 100 elements and let syntactic sugar, [a special rule to make things easier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), initialize it with a copy if a string literal. `char myChars[100] = hello;` says make an array of 100 characters and attempt to initialize it with a pointer. There is no syntactic sugar to make the last leap of logic from pointer to `char` to pointer to string literal.

Comment: @jdex: You've got around the type problem, but now you've hit a more general rule that arrays can't be copied (except in the special case for string literals). Now we're into the territory of perhaps surprising exceptions that are there for historical reasons. The two statements are not equivalent because `"hello"` is a literal but `hello` is a variable. Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

You need to differentiate between *pointer* and *arrays*.

The following defines a pointer to constant text:
`const char* hello="hello";`

The following defines an array:
`char myChars[100];`

You are trying to assigning a pointer to a single slot of an array:
`char myChars[100] = hello;`

Your best bet is to use `std::string`.

In embedded programming, I often use:
`static const char hello_text[] = "Hello";`

I let the compiler determine the size of the array.

Comment: *You are trying to assigning a pointer to a single slot of an array:*: not really. This is not an assignment, but an initialization and a pointer is not a proper initializer for a `char` array.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> char myChars[100] = hello;
> ```

A `char[]` array cannot be initialized from a pointer type (`hello`), since their types are different.

As the compiler error message says it could be initialized using a char array literal like:

```
char myChars[100] = "hello";
```

or

```
char myChars[100] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

`"hello"` or `{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' }` will both deduce to a `char[6]` array type, that can be used as initialization code for `myChars`.